# Can I style an eventClickLimit popover in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar v2.3.1 and I have eventLimits set to 1, so more then 1 event will show up as a link. I click on the link and a popover shows displaying the events in it. Can I style this popover? or do I have to create my own popover and style it myself? I would like to change it's position from center of day to bottom and maybe change a few other things.

```js
$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next', //today',
            center: 'title',
            //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        eventLimit: 1,
        //eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views
        //views: {
        //    agenda: {
        //        eventLimit: 2 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
        //    }
        //},
        events: '/ManageSpaces/GetDiaryEvents/',

        //eventLimitClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
        //    var s = cellInfo.segs;
        //},
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { //function (data, event, view) {
            //var s = cellInfo.segs;
            $("#eventDetails.collapse").collapse('toggle');
        },
        dayClick: function (data, event, view) {
            $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'bottom',
                container: 'body',
                title: function () {
                    return $("#day-popover-head").html();
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $("#day-popover-content").html();
                }
            });
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            if ($calPopOver)
                $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
            $calPopOver = $(this).popover('show');
        }
    });
```

Comment: it can be done, but you will have to modify many parts. It might also conflict the the CSS.

Comment: So then I guess it would be easier to call my own popover within a function callback and put all events inside it? I'm new to JS and FullCalendar and made my own bootstrap popover for a dayClick but I'm afraid I would loose the fullcalendar eventClick info if I created my own popover for the eventLimitClick popover. With the eventClickLimit popover the clicking on events in the popover calls the fullcalendar eventClick. I want to maintain this!! Is that possible?

Comment: yea if I were you, i would create my own popover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Usually and that doesn't sound like it would be difficult. Unfortunately the js above doesn't tell us much as they obviously hook into the fullcalendar plugin which takes care of the html generation. You'll need to see what html it creates.

To figure this stuff out I usually use ie or firefoxe's dev tools or firebug (hit f12 when viewing the results on the site). They have element inspectors which will let you click on the generated html elements and see what css hooks are created and the styles that apply to the element from which style sheets or inline styles. Some basic familiarity with these get me through most of these kind of issues.

If you are able to extract the generated html at least for the section you're interested in or provide a link then that would help heaps.